# Modal dialog - new button to close modal

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog, close

I have a modal dialog popup that is timed to appear once a week. What I now need to create is a button that closes the modal dialog - I want to hide the top right corner button and replace it with a simple input box button placed within the middle of my modal dialog - any help appreciated.

[Other question in regards to creating the popup modal is located here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157718/create-a-modal-dialog-popup-on-load-which-would-appear-only-once-a-day)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SP.UI.ModalDialog Close button](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/sp-ui-modaldialog-close-button)

Answer (score 1):

you have {showClose} property which is used in the options for the modal dialog. Make it false. [refer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx) & [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/sp-ui-modaldialog-close-button)

For the custom button you have to create it inside your modal HTML & then on click call the modal close.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Anand - I am reasonable new to JavaScript and eve newer to scripting in the modal HTML. To you have a code example to share with me?

Comment: Hi Anand - I did add the showClose to the options of my parent page script block and set it to false. I did need further script to close the window which is set out below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I have the code I need. Just a small amount of JavaScript. I have inserted a SEWP on my modal dialog page with the below code to close this window.
The link above to my previous code I have a page that onload launches a modal dialog. I wanted to hide the close button and add a new button which would close the dialog.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function closePopup() {
     window.frameElement.cancelPopUp();
     return false;
    }
</script>
  <div id="confirmBut" style="margin:0;">
     <input onclick="closePopup();" title="Close this message" type="button"
    value="Click here to confirm you accept and understand this message"  
   style="margin: 0; border-radius:5px; width:500px; height:50px; 
    background-color:red; border: 1px grooved grey; font-size:16px; 
    color:white; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;">
 </div>
```

I know I am able to put the css on the button elsewhere but I have popped it on the item.